# linux c++ xlib, how to use XSaveContext and XFindContext (example provided)

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

for `XNextEvent(display,&e)` returned by some windows I need to access to the class to whom this `window` belong, after some searchs on the web and books, [XSaveContext](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XSaveContext.html) and [XFindContext](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XFindContext.html) looks to be usefull, but I didn't found any example of using. So let's try :

I have a `class Metallica`, I would like to save the adress of a `Metallica object` when the `constructor` is called in a `XContext` :

```
class Metallica{
  private:
    Window window;
    int i;
    .
    .
  public:
    Metallica(...,int j, XContext *context){
      .
      .
      i=j;
      //XSaveContext(display, this->window, *context, this); // don't work
      XSaveContext(display, this->window, *context, XPointer(this));
      .
      .
      void MasterOfPuppet(){
        cout << i << endl;
      };
      void FadeToBlack(){
        cout << "OK" << endl;
      };
    };

};
```

so now in my xevent loop I want to get the adress back of one Metallica object,

```
// at the declaration area :
// XContext Metallica_Context;
// XPointer *XPointerToOneMetallicaObject;

XFindContext(display,
             e.xany.window,
             Metallica_Context,
             XPointerToOneMetallicaObject );

Metallica *SandMan = (Metallica*)(*XPointerToOneMetallicaObject);

SandMan->FadeToBlack();    // no problem
SandMan->MasterOfPuppet(); // return a segmentation fault
```

So I do something wrong, but what ?

Comment: Crystal ball: You are storing a pointer to a Metallica that was created (and then destroyed) on the stack. Also, should be `EnterSandMan` and 'MasterOfPuppets`. I wholeheartedly endorse this variable naming convention.

Comment: to "crystal balls" : it would make sense, but the `Metallica` object is not destroyed,actually, it's not declared dynamically so I don't have to destroy it. To Casey, I hope Lars won't sue me... when my stomach get full, I'll add more code

Comment: I would avoid using Xlib, and try to use some higher level toolkit like Qt....

Comment: I don't want to use Qt, or GTK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I wrong, when I call `XFindContext()` the parameter `e.xany.window` can be called by 'any' window, so even ones not made by a `Metallica`, then calling `MasterOfPuppet()` do shit... so I need to protect the call that's it!

well, here a basic (I don't protect the call, but in this case that don't do shit) working code (this code can be used by you to see how `XContext` can be used, lucky you...) :

```
//g++ test.cc -lX11
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<X11/Xlib.h>
#include<X11/Xutil.h>

Display *display;


class Metallica{
  private:
    Window window;
    int i;

  public:
    Metallica(int j, XContext *context){
      i=j;
      this->window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display,DefaultRootWindow(display),100,100,100,100,0,0,0);
      XSelectInput(display, this->window, ExposureMask|ButtonReleaseMask|KeyReleaseMask);
      XMapWindow(display,this->window);
      XSaveContext(display, this->window, *context, XPointer(this));
    };
    void MasterOfPuppet(){
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
    };
    void FadeToBlack(){
      std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main(){
  XContext Metallica_context;
  XPointer *XPointerToOneMetallicaObject;
  XEvent e;
  int DoNotStop=1;

  display = XOpenDisplay(0);

  Metallica OneMetallicaObject(2,&Metallica_context);
  Metallica *SandMan;

  while(DoNotStop){
    XNextEvent(display, &e);
    switch(e.type){
    case Expose : XFlush(display); break;
    case ButtonRelease : XFindContext(display,e.xany.window,Metallica_context,XPointerToOneMetallicaObject);
                         SandMan = (Metallica*)(*XPointerToOneMetallicaObject);
                         SandMan->MasterOfPuppet();
                         break;
    case KeyRelease    : DoNotStop=0; break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```